# Getting the environment variables in service workers in reactjs application

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, service-worker

How can I get(or use) the environment variables in service workers of reactjs application.

Comment: probably have to install a webpack plugin that coppies your env vars to your forntend app. this is dangerous for things like private keys because someone can get all your secret keys. so make sure they are not important/secret.

Comment: Actually I wanted private key only in service worker.

Comment: service workers run in the client. do not put private keys in there

Comment: @JoeLloyd I think that's the whole point of their question.